# Twilio Functions - accessing incoming message info

Tags: node.js, function, twilio

I am trying to use a twilio function to write incoming message data to a database. How do I access the incoming message data (.from, .body) to feed to my database within the function?

Here is what I tried- using context.from and context.body to get the incoming message phone number and message body. The database record insert works but it has blank data for phone and body. I don't think "context.from" and "context.body" is the correct way to access that data.

my function....

```
const airtable = require("airtable");
const twilio = require("twilio");

exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
 const base = new airtable({
   apiKey: context.AIRTABLE_API_KEY,
 }).base(context.AIRTABLE_BLUE_LIGHTNING);
 base("feed").create(
   [
     {
       fields: {
         phone: context.from,
         MSG: context.body,
       },
     },
   ],
   function (error, records) {
     if (error) {
       console.error(error);
       callback(error);
       return;
     } else {
       callback(null, "Success!");
     }
   }
 );
};
```

Comment: Event object, not context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.from` calls the parameters.
`context.YOUR_STORED_VARIABLE` calls any environment variables you store in the configure tab